# Azure S2S Outbound NAT Translation

Tags: azure, vpn, nat

I have a S2S VPN connection with an external party which works fine. However, they have advised that when requests are sent over the VPN tunnel to them, they want to see the request as coming from a public IP address, rather than from our private address range.

Is there a way to configure this in Azure?

For info, we are using the standard Azure VPN gateway as opposed to a third part device from the marketplace.

Thanks
David

Answer (score 0):

If I am correctly understanding, they want to requests are sent over VPN via a public IP address, rather than from our private address range. I don't think it's possible since a VPN extends the **[virtual private network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network)** across the public network. and enables users to send and receive data across shared or public networks as if their computing devices were directly connected to the private network.

You could create a VPN tunnel between the local virtual network and Azure virtual network via S2S VPN gateway. The tunneling protocol is used to encapsulate and encrypt the data going to and from your device and the internet. You only can communicate with the Azure virtual network via the private address range if using VPN.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Your understanding is inline with mine. The weird thing is they are adamant this is a configuration they have with several other clients. My only thought is hiding behind the public IP must be a feature of their firewall device... that said, I can't see how the incoming response would be correctly routed through the VPN tunnel to ensure correct decryption in this scenario.

Comment: I agree with your thought that hiding behind the public IP is probably a feature of their firewall device. As far as I know, the [Azure VPN gateway S2S connection](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2017/06/28/step-by-step-configuring-a-site-to-site-vpn-gateway-between-azure-and-on-premise/) has no such feature of NAT. I'd like to suggest opening a ticket with [Microsoft Premium support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/premier) for confirming if there is a solution. Hope this helps.

Comment: You can NAT to a different DIP, but all of the processes that NAT to a public IP will cause the traffic to go over the internet, and not the VPN tunnel.